# Poner en una línea estas reglas de htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Me gustaría saber si hay posibilidad de aunar estas dos reglas en una sola:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/noticia/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ noticias.php?ID=$2&web_idioma=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/news/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ noticias.php?ID=$2&web_idioma=$1 [L]
```

Como veis sólo se alterna la palabra noticia y news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías unirlas usando el operador de coincidencia (`|`).
Así por ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(news|noticia)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ noticias.php?ID=$3&web_idioma=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, lo he intentado pero no me funciona.

Comment: @JetLagFox, ¿has tenido en cuenta de modificar el `$2` por `$3`?

Comment: ¡Se me había olvidado! ¡Gracias!